# Nillable for required attribute

Tags: visualforce, required-field

I'm wondering meaning of "nillable" used in the required attribute below:

```
  <apex:inputField value="{!Case.Invoiced_Tons__c}" required="{!not($ObjectType.Case.fields.Invoiced_Tons__c.nillable)}"/>
```

When this field will be required?What is nillable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `isNillable()` method of the `DescribeFieldResult` Schema class:

> Returns true if the field is nillable, false otherwise. A nillable
> field can have empty content. A non-nillable field must have a value
> for the object to be created or saved.

Read more about all methods here: [DescribeFieldResult Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm)

And here are related posts:

- [sObject Required Field with Dynamic Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40978/sobject-required-field-with-dynamic-apex)
- [How to tell whether a field is required or not in Apex by describe fields](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16101/how-to-tell-whether-a-field-is-required-or-not-in-apex-by-describe-fields)